# Degeneracies for Fermions and Boson like Electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle

Consider the helium atom to be a fixed point nucleus (with charge 2$e$) with two spin-half fermion electrons. What is the degeneracy of the ground state? If the two-electron was a spin-half boson, hypothetically, what would be the degeneracy of the He atom's ground state?

This question is confusing me on several levels. The first part, I am assuming that the $m_s = + 1/2$ for both electrons. Since it is a fermion, it has to obey Pauli exclusion, so the ground state would have to be $1s^12s^1$ for helium (they both can not occupy the lowest $1s$ energy level since their spins are identical). Degeneracy (based on how I understand it), are multiple quantum states which have the same energy. What exactly is the energy state here if we are split between two energy levels? Are we looking for another electron configuration that has one electron in both $n=1$ and $n=2$?

In the case where they are half bosons, we now have the option to break Pauli exclusion. Thus they can occupy $1s^2$ even though there $m_s = +1/2$. Again, I do not see where the degeneracy is in this configuration (there are supposedly 3).

Could someone help clarify my thinking on what this question is asking?

Comment: Two electrons can both occupy $1s$ if their spins are opposite (even though the total $S$ is always 1/2 for an electron, there are still two spin states).

Comment: I think I may be confused by the language. The "spin quantum number" $s$ determines the magnitude $|S| = \sqrt{s(s+1)}$. Then what is $m_s$ called? How can I tell if they are talking about $s = 1/2$ or $m_s = \pm 1/2$

Comment: $m_s$ is sometimes called the magnetic quantum number if I remember correctly, but you can just say this is the z component of the spin.

Comment: I think $m_l$ is magnetic quantum number.... https://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/Q/quantum_number.html. This is why I am confused in this question. Is "spin-half" referring to $s$ or $m_s$. Are they putting a restriction on the quantum state ($n$, $l$, $m_l$, $m_s$) where $m_s = +1/2$ or just stating that $s = 1/2$

Comment: Spin-half means $s=1/2$. $s$ comes first and determines the "spin". Then after  $s$ is fixed, $m_s$ is valued in $-s, -s+1, \dots, s$, so there are $2s+1$ possible spin states.